# MySQL query only select not matching pairs

Tags: mysql

I don't know if it's possible but I'm trying to `SELECT` not matching columns, let's say I have a table with columns:

`id`, `user_name`, `color1`, `color2`, `fruit1`, `fruit2`

I would like to select a row by id only if `color1` and `color2` OR! `fruit1`, `fruit2` are now equal to each other. If `color1` == `color2` OR `fruit1` == `fruit2` the query should return 0 rows. If `color1` <> `color2` and `fruit1` == `fruit2` the row should return only `id`, `user_name`, `color1`, `color2`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT  id, user_name, color1, color2
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (color1 <> color2) AND (fruit1 = fruit2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just expand the logic and include both cases:

```
SELECT id, user_name, color1, color2, fruit1, fruit2
FROM myTable
WHERE (color1 <> color2 AND fruit1 = fruit2)
OR (color1 = color2 AND fruit1 <> fruit2)
```

From your comment, you will have to try something a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT nonmatching.id, user_name, prop_name, value1, value2
FROM
(
    SELECT id, user_name, prop_name, value1, value2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, user_name, 'color' AS prop_name, 
            color1 AS value1, color2 AS value2
        FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, user_name, 'fruit' AS prop_name, 
            fruit1 AS value1, fruit2 AS value2
        FROM myTable
    ) propertyExpanded
    WHERE value1 <> value2
) nonmatching
```

If you only want to return rows with one mismatch, for example, you can add the following:

```
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, COUNT(1) AS mismatchCount = 1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, user_name, 'color' AS prop_name, 
            color1 AS value1, color2 AS value2
        FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, user_name, 'fruit' AS prop_name, 
            fruit1 AS value1, fruit2 AS value2
        FROM myTable
    ) propertyExpanded
    WHERE value1 <> value2
    GROUP BY id
) nonmatchingCount ON nonmatching.id = nonmatchingCount.id
WHERE nonmatchingCount.mismatchCount = 1
```

Comment: I have many columns to compare, I can't include all the cases. BTW this method returns matching tables as well. I only want to return a data set with `id` and not matching tables.

Comment: @kajab Take a look at my edit and see if this is closer to what you are trying to get

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT id,
       user_name,
       color1,
       color2
FROM mytable
WHERE (color1 = color2) != (fruit1 = fruit2)
```

Trick here is that I am comparing results of comparisons as boolean values.

This approach can be generalized to support more than two kinds of exact single data matches. Namely, you can use similar trick by counting matches like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (color1 = color2)
    + (fruit1 = fruit2)
    + ...
    + (kind1  = kind2)
    = 1
```

In this query, boolean `FALSE` or `TRUE` are implicitly cast to `0` or `1`.

Thus, this query is going to yield rows only when **exactly one** kind is matching.